# How to get Thumbnails for video

Tags: java, android, thumbnails

I want to get Thumbnails for Videos which are stored in Server...And Grid view will be used to display Thumbnails...I am using android 3.0

Here is the code that I have used:

```
String[] videoFileList = {
  "http://129.0.0.213:8080/playback/201203/thumbs/00068.flv_img/0000003.jpg",

};

public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

 public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
   String[] objects) {
  super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  View row = convertView;
  if(row==null){
   LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
   row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
  }


  ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

  Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

  return row;
 }

}
```

Please Help Me...

Comment: What language? What platform? (guessing this is Java, from the `@Override` attribute, but not sure).

Comment: I am using Android 3.0...And i am not using any real device...

Comment: @Oded:java is the language i am using..

Answer (score 0):

The createVideoThumbnail method's first parameter is the video file path, where as if i understanding correctly from your query, you are passing a file path to '.jpg' file.

Check the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

```
bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.
createVideoThumbnail(THE_PATH_OF_VIDEO_FILE, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

Comment: I tried with link but i got the error and then i changed the code which i copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270713/get-a-image-of-a-url-dynamicly..... and its printing values in logcat but its not showing any values in emulator....please help me......

Comment: Actually I am not getting any error... But its not displaying  Thumbnails and video details on emulator (means i am getting blank screen)....